# Native toplink having large entity size

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, toplink

My application is running fine with some memory issues, i am using native toplink with spring 2.5, Each entity of my application is consuming about 21MB size, after investigation it came to know that those entities used `ValueHolder Interface` (indirection) for lazy loading having large size.

For example :

```
class Customer
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private ValueHolderInterface customerAddress = new ValueHolder();
    // getter...setter...
}
class address{
    private Long id;
    private String city;
    private String country;
}
```

Customer entity has `CustomerAddres` `ValueHolderInterface`, showing 20MB even CustomerAddress has few String properties

**Logging shows each property size.** 
Customer [id=24 bytes, name=50 bytes, firstName=80 bytes, lastName=80 bytes, customerAddress=**20625584 bytes**, customerAddress=**20625584 bytes**]

**query**:
is ValueHolder eating memory ? 
is there any way to get rid of the issue ?
is toplink applying some kind of run-time weaving here

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A ValueHolder doesn't use up very much memory, probably less than 100 bytes, certainly not 20MB.

Without seeing how you have your mappings set up, my guess is that you have a one-to-many mapping between Customer and Address, but your foreign key mappings aren't set up correctly, so TopLink is doing a Cartesian join and loading every address in your whole database for each customer.